# JavaScript - Difference between these two functions

Tags: javascript, function

sorry if this has been asked a million times before. I'm a C++ programmer figuring out JavaScript and following a tutorial. While testing some stuff I wondered what the difference was between making a function like this:

```
let argument = 
{
    mymethod() 
    { 
        console.log("WE DID IT");
    },
}
```

Versus Like This:

```
let argument = 
{
    output: function()
    {
        console.log("WE DID IT");
    }
}
```

They can each be called the same way. What's the difference in practicality and behind the scenes? Thanks!

Comment: Very little. The method version can't be instantiated, but if that's not something you're doing, the difference won't affect you

Comment: Thanks for that, the link was helpful. You came in faster than a bullet!

Comment: Jesus literally asked the same question 4 hours ago, and CretainPerformance answered it - so, no wonder he was so quick :p